# jsonformatter showing Invalid json format

Tags: json

I am trying to send a json format in bloom but it's saying invalid json format.

```
    {
  "requestId": {
    'value': 'Hello'
  },
  "identifier": {
    'value': {
      'value': '3440869'
    },
    'refType': 1
  },
  "userInfo": {
    'customerStatus': 'CLOSED'
  }
}
```

It's giving me

```
Parse error on line 2:
..."requestId": {
    'value': 'Hello'

----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Comment: replace the single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: @Kevin Please check edited question

Comment: Sorry - I mean single quotes aren't valid in json. If you replace the single quotes with double quotes the json will be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace all the single quotes with double quotes. It is then valid json.

```
{
    "requestId": {
        "value": "Hello"
    },
    "identifier": {
        "value": {
            "value": "3440869"
        },
        "refType": 1
    },
    "userInfo": {
        "customerStatus": "CLOSED"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace *ALL* single quotes with double quotes,

You can verify your JSON format in any json editor, for example:

https://jsoneditoronline.org/

[checking format with jsoneditoronline.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ePUS.png)

here is the correct format:

```
{
  "requestId": {
    "value": "Hello"
  },
  "identifier": {
    "value": {
      "value": "3440869"
    },
    "refType": 1
  },
  "userInfo": {
    "customerStatus": "CLOSED"
  }
}
```